# add fields to contact.php

Tags: php, email, templates, webforms

I got a template online... They included this contact.php - And how do I add extra fields so this contact.php will send it to me.

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

$email = $_POST['email'];


//$error[] = preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i', $_POST['email']) ? '' : 'INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS';
if(!eregi("^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*" ."@"."([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+"."\\.[a-z]{2,}"."$",$email )){
    $error.="Invalid email address entered";
    $errors=1;
}
if($errors==1) echo $error;
else{
    $values = array ('name','email','message');
    $required = array('name','email','message');

    $your_email = "myemail@live.ca";
    $email_subject = "New Message: ".$_POST['subject'];
    $email_content = "new message:\n";

    foreach($values as $key => $value){
      if(in_array($value,$required)){
        if ($key != 'subject' && $key != 'company') { if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS'; exit; }
        }
        $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
      }
    }

    if(@mail($your_email,$email_subject,$email_content)) {
        echo 'Message sent!'; 
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }
}
?>
```

The HTML contact page is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contactform').submit(function(){                  
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        $.post(action, { 
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            telephone: $('#telephone').val(),
            company: $('#company').val(),
            subject: $('#subject').val(),
            message: $('#message').val()
        },
            function(data){
                $('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled','');
                $('.response').remove();
                $('#contactform').before('<p class="response">'+data+'</p>');
                $('.response').slideDown();
                if(data=='Message sent!') $('#contactform').slideUp();
            }
        ); 
        return false;
    });
});
// ]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="blok_header">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="search">
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div class="withe_bg">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="menu">        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <div class="body">
        <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>

        <div class="left">
          <h2>Send us a Message:</h2>
          <p>Please use this convenient form to your send your message, and we will get back to you shortly.</p>
          <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contactform">
            <ol>
              <li>
                <label for="name">Name <span class="red">*</span></label>
                <input id="name" name="name" class="text" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <label for="telephone">Telephone <span class="red"></span></label>
                <input id="telephone" name="telephone" class="text" />
              </li>
              <li>              
                <label for="email">Your email <span class="red">*</span></label>
                <input id="email" name="email" class="text" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <label for="company">Company</label>
                <input id="company" name="company" class="text" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                <input id="subject" name="subject" class="text" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <label for="message">Message <span class="red">*</span></label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
              </li>
              <li class="buttons">
                <input type="image" name="imageField" id="imageField" src="images/send.gif" class="send" />
                <div class="clr"></div>
              </li>
          </ol>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="right last">

           <p>&nbsp;</p>
           <p>
           </p>

           </div>

          <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<div class="FBG">
  <div class="FBG_resize">
  <div class="clr"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<div class="FBG">
  <div class="FBG_resize">
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer_resize">
    <p class="leftt">&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And still does not work.....

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want the contact mail to be sent to you also,right? if so try the following code. `mail` is the php mail function which done the trick. For more reference you can check the [MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];

//$error[] = preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i', $_POST['email']) ? '' : 'INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS';
if(!eregi("^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*" ."@"."([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+"."\\.[a-z]{2,}"."$",$email )){
    $error.="Invalid email address entered";
    $errors=1;
}
if($errors==1) echo $error;
else{
    $values = array ('name','email','message');
    $required = array('name','email','message');

    $your_email = "seanbridge@live.ca";
    $email_subject = "New Message: ".$_POST['subject'];
    $email_content = "new message:\n";

    foreach($values as $key => $value){
      if(in_array($value,$required)){
        if ($key != 'subject' && $key != 'company') { if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS'; exit; }
        }
        $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
      }
    }

    if(@mail($your_email,$email_subject,$email_content)) {
        echo 'Message sent!'; 
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }

    $myEmail = "myemai@your.com";//put your email address here

    if(@mail($myEmail,$email_subject,$email_content)) {
        echo 'Message sent!'; 
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this isn't the form itself, it's the form processor. you probably have an HTML file somewhere with the form, posting to this contact.php file.

anyway, it looks like you have to match the # of fields you're requesting in the form to the # of items (with the correct names) in the $values array.  It also looks like you can require certain ones in the $required array.

change the $your_email to your email address.

you should get the emails through the form.

does that answer your question? It wasn't terribly specific.

Comment: I reposted... i did the edits and I'm only get this via email:

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to email to multiple people, you should take a look at the parameters section (the To section)[here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). This will go in your

`$your_email = "myemail@live.ca";`

Here's an example:

`$your_email = "<user@example.com>, Another User <anotheruser@example.com>";`

That should send it to user@example.com and anotheruser@example.com

Answer (score 0):

The fix is:

edit the: $required = array('name','email','telephone','message');

And it works... 100% - thanks all...